# JsFiddle: Is the Library "Load Type" referring to the library or my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, jsfiddle

This would seem quite obvious, but I am not so sure, and the [documentation is ambiguous](https://docs.jsfiddle.net/panels-settings).

I am using jsFiddle (this one in particular, https://jsfiddle.net/suterma/dmqr5fe2/7/ but the question is more general)

```
$("textarea, input").bind("paste", function(e){
    //...
});
```

I use jQuery with it and it makes a difference in functionality, whether I set the jQuery Library's load type to "on Load" or "bottom of head".

**Now, is this load type actually referring to how the jQuery library is loaded or how my code fragment is loaded?**

I tried to use the developer mode to drill down the result pane, but is quite heavily convoluted, and I have not figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it out by Inspecting the inner iframe, or by logging the document's `innerHTML`. Eg, add this to your code:

```
console.log(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

and you get

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- LOOK HERE: ----------------------------------------------------------------->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">


  <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
      textarea{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  }

 input{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  }
  </style>


  <!-- TODO: Missing CoffeeScript 2 -->

  <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    // LOOK HERE: ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    $(window).load(function(){

console.log(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
$("textarea, input").bind("paste", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  var cd = e.originalEvent.clipboardData;

  var text = cd.getData("text/plain");

  $(this).val(text.trim());
});

    });

  //]]></script>

</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="pastezone" placeholder="Copy someting with leading and trailing spaces here, then it gets trimmed!"></textarea>

<input id="pastebox" placeholder="Copy someting with leading and trailing spaces here, then it gets trimmed!">



  <script>
    // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
      window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        slug: ""
      }], "*")
    }

    // always overwrite window.name, in case users try to set it manually
    window.name = "result"
  </script>


</body>
```

As you can see, the library (jQuery) is being loaded *immediately*, in a `<script>` tag in the head. In contrast, your code is put inside a `$(window).load(function(){` callback.

Note that the method of running your code when the document runs depends on the library used. Eg, if you deselect jQuery and use D3.js (or any other library instead), your code is instead put inside a `window.onload = function() {` callback.